# nmap silent with specific installation directory

Tags: installation, nmap

Anyone have try to do the installation? it always install to c:\program files\WinPcap directory regardless of the parameter

winpcap-nmap-4.02.exe /S /D="C:\tools\WinPcap\"

http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2008/q2/834

Comment: I'm always installing it in the `/usr` on Linux  or in `/usr/local` on FreeBSD. I advise you do that too. `C:\tools` is just wrong.

Comment: This is Windows machine, I need to install in specific directory, thanks

Comment: Wrong on my command? This is requirement, cannot install in winpcap in the default program dir

Answer (score 0):

While there is no way [currently](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/311) to pass a separate `/D` parameter to the bundled WinPcap installer from the Nmap installer command line, the `winpcap-nmap` installer has supported direct use of the `/D` command since version 4.1.2 in 2010. You appear to be using version 4.02, from 2007. Try upgrading.

Comment: My bad, I'm using 4.13 from the beginning 


c:\>winpcap-nmap-4.13.exe  /S /D="C:\tools\WinPcap\"

c:\>dir "c:\Program Files\WinPcap"
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 8066-9E37

 Directory of c:\Program Files\WinPcap

02/24/2016  05:38 AM    <DIR>          .
02/24/2016  05:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/15/2015  04:30 PM            13,713 LICENSE
11/15/2015  04:30 PM           118,520 rpcapd.exe
02/24/2016  05:38 AM            59,158 uninstall.exe
               3 File(s)        191,391 bytes
               2 Dir(s)     951,795,712 bytes free

c:\>